# Push key is no longer valid on the Apple Developer Portal

Tags: ios, expo

I am trying to create custom expo client. When it comes to chosing a way to generate push keys, two options are shown:

1. Provide my own key
2. Let expo handle the process

If I choose `Provide my own key` option (that I get from my expo developer page on the expo website), I get an error saying that:

> ✖ This Push Key is no longer valid on the Apple Developer Portal

If I choose to `Let expo handle the process`, it says that:

> You can have only two Apple Keys generated on your Apple Developer
> account. Please revoke the old ones or reuse existing from your other
> apps. Please remember that Apple Keys are not application specific!

When I log into my developer account and look at two of my keys, they are indeed different from the one that is shown on my expo page - their IDs are different. Seems like existing authentication key that is shown on expo is invalid for some reason.

**If my current APN authentication key is invalid, then how do notifications in my app still work? And how should I build my custom expo client without breaking my existing, published app?**